# loading google map in ajax div problems :-/ - jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-maps

I got some problems loading google map into a jquery $.post...

the output is correct in firebug.. but it wont show the map :-/

Any idea how to fix?

```
 $.post('/ajax/index.php', {action:somedata}, function(data){
     $(div).slideDown(500,function(){
         $(div).html(data);
      });
 },'html');
```

and then I load the data via. echo in the /ajax/index.php action

```
<div id="map" style="width: 540px; height: 500px; align:center;"></div>
```

Comment: does firebug show the map images being requested? We need more info to help (a link to your page would be best if you could upload)

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `div` var?

Comment: There are three images (ajax-loader_small.gif, closelabel.gif and blank.gif) not found -according to Firefox, does your js/jQuery require those images in some way?

Comment: hmm no, i'm not using the images for loading the map ... :/

Comment: Also, since posting the map has now made itself visible...it took a long time to get there though, and oddly doesn't seem willing to show the map again. (FF 3.0.13/Ubuntu 8.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution ..

in the ajax file i did this: `<img src="/gfx/blank.gif" alt="" onload="load();" />`

The problem was that it did't initialize() the page, when clicked... but it does now. :)